# Error Printing LinkedList of Structs after Deleting Node

Tags: c, linked-list, nodes

I'm making an employee linked list. Does all the usual stuff, Adding, Searching and Updating. I'm trying to get the delete function working but after the Node is supposedly deleted I can't print the linked list to see. Here is the complete code, as well as the error message. Thanks for taking the time to read this.

Unhandled exception at 0x0FA4FB53 (msvcr120d.dll) in LinkedList.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xFEEEFEEE.

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


#define ID_LENGTH 25
#define NAME_LENGTH 25
#define address_LENGTH 25
#define department_LENGTH 25
#define joinDate_LENGTH 25
#define email_LENGTH 30
int mymenu;

//Create employee Structure
typedef struct employee{
    char* ID;
    char* name;
    char* department;
    char* address;
    char* joinDate;
    double salary;
    char* email;
    struct employee *next;
}employee;

//Declare Function Prototypes
int login();
int Menu();
void Add(struct employee *head);
void search(struct employee *head, char*);
void update(struct employee *head, char*);
void outputList();
struct employee* searchForEmployee(char* );
employee* new_employee(char*, char*, char*, char*, char*, double, char*);
employee* insert_by_employee(employee*, employee*);
void removeEmployee(char *);
void print_list(employee*); // prints out the LinkedList


employee* head = NULL; 
employee* tail = NULL;
employee* temp = NULL;
employee* current = NULL;


//this stores the employee that comes before the employee that is found by the searchforEmployee
struct employee *empBeforeEmptoDelete = NULL;

int main() {
    int num = 0;
    int MenuChoice = 0;

    Menu();


    FILE *in;
    char* ID = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char*) * ID_LENGTH);
    char* name = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char*) * NAME_LENGTH);
    char* department = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char*) * department_LENGTH);
    char* address = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char*) * address_LENGTH);
    char* joinDate = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char*) * joinDate_LENGTH);
    double salary = 0;
    char* email = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char*) * email_LENGTH);


    if ((in = fopen("Employees.txt", "r")) == NULL) //Did the file successfully open?
    {
        printf("The input file failed to open.\n");
        printf("Program cannot continue. Exiting. . .\n");
        return 1; //Exit Program
    }


    while (!feof(in)) //Check for file end
    {
        //Read first data value to kickstart.
        if (fscanf(in, "%s %s %s %s %s %lf %s", ID, name, department, address, joinDate, &salary, email) == EOF) {
            break;
        }

        employee* hold = new_employee(ID, name, department, address, joinDate, salary, email);
        head = insert_by_employee(head, hold);

    }

    //3. ------Print the new List------
    //print_list(head);
    do
    {
        switch (MenuChoice = Menu())
        {
        case 1:
        {
            Add(head);
            break;
        }
        case 2:
        {
            char text[10];
            printf("Enter the text to search for :");
            scanf("%s", text);
            //search(head, text);
            searchForEmployee(text);
            break;
        }
        case 3:
        {
            char text[10];
            printf("Enter the ID to update for :");
            scanf("%s", text);
            update(head, text);
            break;
        }
        case 4:
        {
            outputList();
            char text[10];
            printf("Enter the ID to remove :");
            scanf("%s", text);
            removeEmployee(text);
            outputList();
            break;

        }
        case 5:
        {
            print_list(head);
            break;
        }
        case 6:
        {

            break;
        }
        case 7:
        {
            break;
        }
        case 8:
        {
            exit(0);
            break;
        }
        default:
        {
            printf("\nInvalid Selection");
            break;
        }
        }
    } while (MenuChoice < 8);

    system("Pause");
    printf("\n\n\n");
    return 1; //Exit Success
}
employee* new_employee(char* id, char* name, char* department, char* address, char* joinDate, double salary, char* email) {

    //Create new employee and malloc space
    employee* new = (employee*)malloc(sizeof(struct employee));
    new->ID = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * ID_LENGTH);
    new->name = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * NAME_LENGTH);
    new->department = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * department_LENGTH);
    new->address = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * address_LENGTH);
    new->joinDate = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * joinDate_LENGTH);
    new->email = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * email_LENGTH);



    //Set data
    strcpy(new->ID, id);
    strcpy(new->name, name);
    strcpy(new->department, department);
    strcpy(new->address, address);
    strcpy(new->joinDate, joinDate);
    new->salary = salary;
    strcpy(new->email, email);
    //Retun a pointer to the node
    return new;

}

//Inserts new node into an alphabetically sorted linked list.
employee* insert_by_employee(employee* head, employee* new)
{
    employee* current = NULL;
    current = head;
    if (current == NULL || strcmp(current->department, new->department) > 0)
    {
        new->next = current;
        return new;
    }
    else {

        while (current->next != NULL && strcmp(current->next->department, new->department) < 0)
        {

            current = current->next;
        }
    }
    new->next = current->next;
    current->next = new;
    return head;

}
struct employee* searchForEmployee(char* id){
    struct employee *empIterator = head;
    char i[] = "Employee ID";
    char n[] = "Name";
    char a[] = "Address";
    char d[] = "Department";
    char jd[] = "Join Date";
    char s[] = "Salary";
    char em[] = "Email";

    while (empIterator != NULL){
        int isEqual = strcmp(empIterator->ID, id);//if the passed in ID is equla to the ID of the node then isEqual will ring true

        if (!isEqual){

            printf("Employee Found\n");
            printf("\n\n|%15s | %15s | %15s | %15s | %15s| %15s | %15s|\n", i, n, a, d, jd, s, em);//header formatting
            printf("|%15s | %15s | %15s |%15s | %15s | %15.2lf| %25s\n", empIterator->ID, empIterator->name, empIterator->address, empIterator->department, empIterator->joinDate, empIterator->salary, empIterator->email);
            //printing out the current node which is the desired employee
            printf("-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
            return empIterator;
        }
        empBeforeEmptoDelete = empIterator->next;

        empIterator = empIterator->next;
    }
    printf("%s was not found\n\n", id);
    return NULL;
}
void print_list(employee* head)
{
    employee* current;
    current = head;
    char i[] = "Employee ID";
    char n[] = "Name";
    char a[] = "Address";
    char d[] = "Department";
    char jd[] = "Join Date";
    char s[] = "Salary";
    char em[] = "Email";


    //Header
    printf("\n\n|%15s | %15s | %15s | %15s | %15s| %15s | %15s|\n", i, n, a, d, jd, s, em);
    printf("--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");


    while (current != NULL)
    {
        printf("|%15s | %15s | %15s |%15s | %15s | %15.2lf| %25s\n", current->ID, current->name, current->address, current->department, current->joinDate, current->salary, current->email);
        current = current->next;
    }
    printf("-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");


    return;
}
int login()
{

    char username[7];
    char password[7];

    printf("\nPlease enter your Username: ");
    scanf("%s", username);
    printf("\nPlease enter your Password: ");
    scanf("%s", password);

    struct login{
        char name[7];
        char password[7];

    };
    struct login details[3];
    fflush(stdin);

    FILE *file;
    file = fopen("login.txt", "r");
    if (file == NULL){
        printf("Can not open the file\n");
        exit(-1);
    }
    fflush(stdin);

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        fscanf(file, "%s %s\n", details[i].name, details[i].password);
    }


    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        if ((strcmp(details[i].name, username) == 0) && (strcmp(details[i].password, password) == 0))
        {
            printf("\nWelcome ");
            Menu();
        }
        fflush(stdin);
    }
}
int Menu()
{
    int Choice = 0;

    do{

        printf("1. Add\n");
        printf("2. Show\n");
        printf("3. Update\n");
        printf("4. Delete\n"); // Write a Function for this
        printf("5. Departments\n");
        printf("6. Employee Report\n");
        printf("7. \n");
        printf("8. Exit\n\n\n\t\tSELECTION = ");

        fflush(stdin);

        scanf("%d", &Choice);
        fflush(stdin);
    } while (Choice < 0 || Choice > 8);

    return(Choice);
}
void Add()
{

    char* ID = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char*) * ID_LENGTH);
    char* name = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char*) * NAME_LENGTH);
    char* department = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char*) * department_LENGTH);
    char* address = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char*) * address_LENGTH);
    char* joinDate = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char*) * joinDate_LENGTH);
    double salary = 0;
    char* email = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char*) * email_LENGTH);


    printf("\nEnter the ID : ");
    scanf("%s", ID);
    printf("\nEnter the new employee name : ");
    scanf("%s", name);
    printf("\nEnter their address : ");
    scanf("%s", address);
    printf("\nEnter their department : ");
    scanf("%s", department);
    printf("\nEnter their start date : ");
    scanf("%s", joinDate);
    printf("\nEnter their salary : ");
    scanf("%lf", &salary);
    printf("\nEnter their email : ");
    scanf("%s", email);


    employee* hold = new_employee(ID, name, department, address, joinDate, salary, email);
    head = insert_by_employee(head, hold);
}
void search(struct employee *head, char *crit)//This function takes in the head pointer and a character array pointer
{
    int choice;//menu choice tracker

    //arrays to hold the header heads
    char i[] = "Employee ID";
    char n[] = "Name";
    char a[] = "Address";
    char d[] = "Department";
    char jd[] = "Join Date";
    char s[] = "Salary";
    char em[] = "Email";

    //sub menu to filter by ID and Name searches
    printf("\nSearch by ");
    printf("\n1 : ID");
    printf("\n2 : Name\n");
    scanf("%d", &choice);

    //if the user wants to search by ID
    if (choice == 1){
        while (head != NULL)
        {
            //compare the ID to the criteria. If its the same then execute this if
            if ((strcmp(head->ID, crit) == 0))
            {
                //print that we found the employee
                printf("Employee Found\n");
                printf("\n\n|%15s | %15s | %15s | %15s | %15s| %15s | %15s|\n", i, n, a, d, jd, s, em);//header formatting
                printf("----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
                printf("|%15s | %15s | %15s |%15s | %15s | %15.2lf| %25s\n", head->ID, head->name, head->address, head->department, head->joinDate, head->salary, head->email);
                //printing out the current node which is the desired employee
                printf("-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
                return;
            }
            head = head->next;//increments the node until we get to the end of the Linked List
        }
        printf("Employee not found\n");//Else there is no Employee with an ID of the entered criteria
    }
    //if the user wants to search by Name
    else if (choice == 2){
        while (head != NULL)
        {
            //compare the Name to the criteria. If its the same then execute this if
            if ((strcmp(head->name, crit) == 0))
            {
                //print that we found the employee
                printf("Employee Found\n");
                printf("\n\n|%15s | %15s | %15s | %15s | %15s| %15s | %15s|\n", i, n, a, d, jd, s, em);//header formatting
                printf("----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
                printf("|%15s | %15s | %15s |%15s | %15s | %15.2lf| %25s\n", head->ID, head->name, head->address, head->department, head->joinDate, head->salary, head->email);
                //printing out the current node which is the desired employee
                printf("----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
                return;
            }
            head = head->next;//increments the node until we get to the end of the Linked List
        }
        printf("Employee not found\n");//Else there is no Employee with an Name of the entered criteria
    }
    else
        printf("Bad input");//Otherwise the user entered a choice out of the range of our handled input
}
void update(struct employee *head, char *crit)//This function takes in the head pointer and a character array pointer
{


    //arrays to hold the header heads
    char i[] = "Employee ID";
    char n[] = "Name";
    char a[] = "Address";
    char d[] = "Department";
    char jd[] = "Join Date";
    char s[] = "Salary";
    char em[] = "Email";

    char id[25];
    char name[25];
    char address[25];
    char department[25];
    char joinDate[25];
    double salary;
    char email[25];


    //if the user wants to search by ID
        while (head != NULL)
        {
            //compare the ID to the criteria. If its the same then execute this if
            if ((strcmp(head->ID, crit) == 0))
            {
                //print that we found the employee
                printf("Employee Found\n");
                printf("\n\n|%15s | %15s | %15s | %15s | %15s| %15s | %15s|\n", i, n, a, d, jd, s, em);//header formatting
                printf("----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
                printf("|%15s | %15s | %15s |%15s | %15s | %15.2lf| %25s\n", head->ID, head->name, head->address, head->department, head->joinDate, head->salary, head->email);
                //printing out the current node which is the desired employee
                printf("-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");

                printf("\nEnter the ID : ");
                scanf("%s", id);
                printf("\nEnter the new employee name : ");
                scanf("%s", name);
                printf("\nEnter their address : ");
                scanf("%s", address);
                printf("\nEnter their department : ");
                scanf("%s", department);
                printf("\nEnter their start date : ");
                scanf("%s", joinDate);
                printf("\nEnter their salary : ");
                scanf("%lf", &salary);
                printf("\nEnter their email : ");
                scanf("%s", email);

                strcpy(head->ID, id);
                strcpy(head->name, name);
                strcpy(head->department, department);
                strcpy(head->address, address);
                strcpy(head->joinDate, joinDate);
                head->salary = salary;
                strcpy(head->email, email);

                printf("Employee Found\n");
                printf("\n\n|%15s | %15s | %15s | %15s | %15s| %15s | %15s|\n", i, n, a, d, jd, s, em);//header formatting
                printf("----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
                printf("|%15s | %15s | %15s |%15s | %15s | %15.2lf| %25s\n", head->ID, head->name, head->address, head->department, head->joinDate, head->salary, head->email);
                //printing out the current node which is the desired employee
                printf("-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");

                return;
            }
            head = head->next;//increments the node until we get to the end of the Linked List
        }
        printf("Employee not found\n");//Else there is no Employee with an ID of the entered criteria
    }
void outputList(){
    char i[] = "Employee ID";
    char n[] = "Name";
    char a[] = "Address";
    char d[] = "Department";
    char jd[] = "Join Date";
    char s[] = "Salary";
    char em[] = "Email";

    struct employee * employees = head;
    printf("Employees Entered\n\n");
    while (employees != NULL){
        printf("Employee Found\n");
        printf("\n\n|%15s | %15s | %15s | %15s | %15s| %15s | %15s|\n", i, n, a, d, jd, s, em);//header formatting
        printf("|%15s | %15s | %15s |%15s | %15s | %15.2lf| %25s\n", employees->ID, employees->name, employees->address, employees->department, employees->joinDate, employees->salary, employees->email);
        printf("-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");

        employees = employees->next;
    }
}
void removeEmployee(char* empID){

    struct employee* empToDelete = NULL;

    empToDelete = searchForEmployee(empID);

    if (empToDelete != NULL){

        printf("%s was deleted\n\n", empID);

        if (empToDelete == head){

            head = empToDelete->next;
        }
        else{
            empBeforeEmptoDelete->next = empToDelete->next;
        }

        free(empToDelete);
    }
    else{
        printf("%s was not found", empID);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in `removeEmployee(char* empID)` function:
***case:***   when node to be deleted is not the head node;

here, first you have to save the pointer of `previous_node` of `delete_node` and then set `previous_node->next` to `delete_node->next`  and delete the `delete_node`.

you haven't saved the pointer of `previous_node`.

```
empBeforeEmptoDelete->next = empToDelete->next;
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with

```
empBeforeEmptoDelete = empIterator->next;
empIterator = empIterator->next;
```

so `empBeforeEmptoDelete` does *not* point to the previous record. Change to

```
empBeforeEmptoDelete = empIterator;
empIterator = empIterator->next;
```